# As soon as my Kinect application starts sending serial data, the user interface freezes in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, arduino, kinect

I wrote up this program in Visual Basic to control a small robot. The program itself essentially just sends the X and Y coordinates of my hands to the Arduino Microprocessor which controls the robot.

For some reason, when the baud rate is set to 115200, required by the arduino Bluetooth board that I am using, the app freezes as soon as it starts sending serial data. Yet, when I set it to 9200, and use my arduino diecimilia, the app does not freeze up.

I need the baud rate to be 115200 as I want to use my arduino Bluetooth to communicate wirelessly with my robot. Any ideas on how to stop it from freezing?

The code sending data to the Arduino

```
Private Sub ArduinoSetSerial()
     Dim ArduinoCom As String = ComPort.text
     _serialPort = New SerialPort()
     _serialPort.PortName = "COM" + Trim(ComPort.Text) 'Gets the ComPort from the Text box in the GUI of the App
     _serialPort.BaudRate = 9200 'When using any other Arduino PLC, this should be set to 9600. In this case, it is set to 115200 as the specififc Arduino PLC we are using requires it.
     _serialPort.DataBits = 8
     _serialPort.Handshake = 0
     _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500
     _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500

End Sub

Private Sub ArduinoOpenSerial()
     If Not _serialPort.IsOpen Then 'Opens the serial port if it isn't already open.
          _serialPort.Open()
     Else
          MsgBox("ARDUINO: SERIAL PORT CANNOT BE OPENED")
     End If
     _continue = True
End Sub

Private Sub ArduinoCloseSerial() 'Defines the CloseSerial Action executed on shutdown
     If _serialPort.IsOpen Then
          _serialPort.Close()
     End If
End Sub

Private Sub ArduinoSendByte(ByVal kinect_x As Single, ByVal kinect_y As Single, ByVal kinect_z As Single, ByVal kinect_j As Integer)
     Dim x, y, z, j As Byte
     Dim sx, sy As Single
     Dim HowOften As Integer
     ComStatus.Text = "NA" 'Set ComStatus Text to NA when not sending data

     x = Math.Abs(CByte(kinect_x)) 'The X co-ordinate of the requested JointID
     y = Math.Abs(CByte(kinect_y)) 'The Y co-ordinate of the requested JointID
     z = CByte(kinect_z) 'The Z co-ordinate of the requested JointID (Not used in this particular application)
     j = CByte(kinect_j) 'JointID
     x = x
     Dim ArduinoBuffer() As Byte = {x, y, z, j}
     If _serialPort.IsOpen Then
          ComStatus.Text = "OK" 'Write OK inthe ComStatus text box in the GUI
          _serialPort.Write(ArduinoBuffer, 0, ArduinoBuffer.Length) 'Actually sends all the information to the Arduino on the specified Serial Port
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Paid advertising link and full source (probably, im not downloading that!), seriously?

Comment: What SDK are you using?  Are you capturing/sending data on the UI thread?

Comment: ... also, please include the relavent bits of code.  We do not need to download your source archive and dig through them all.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey Im using sdk 1.0, im going to try with the latest later today. Also, i included the entire project because i honestly have no idea what im doing wrong, or whether other code i wrote in the project is causing this problem. 

Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: Include the function(s) that are tracking and processing the Kinect data, plus any additional function call that is sending your data to the robot.  We'll start looking there for any items.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey Code: http://pastebin.com/1Adfj0PG This is all the code that collects and sends data from the program to arduino. Included comments

Comment: Try setting up some dummy data in an array and having it send that on a timer (so it is spaced out over time).  My guess is you're sending this all the UI thread, and it takes a lot of resources... thus your UI freezes.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey Hmmm, interesting theory. I will test this tommorrow. Thanks again for your continued help :)